# Set size of points independent from map scale

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In ArcGIS the size of a point feature is constant independent from the map scale. In QGIS when I zoom in the point get smaller and when I zoom out they get bigger. How can I fix the point size?

What I mean is: Assuming the point is a manhole in a street. In the following picture it Looks like we have a very small manhole in a wide street.

[image]

In this image it looks like the manhole covers half of the street width

[image]

Here it seems the manhole is as wide as the street

[image]

Comment: No, the points in both images have the same size, the standard 2 mm.

Comment: yes you are right... I edited my question and tried to explain better what my problem is

Comment: Either set the size of the points to map units, or work with scale-depending visibility.

Comment: You can size using 'map units',even driving the symbol size by an attribute value in your data table /column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work with setting the unit to `Meter at Scale` or `Map Units`

[image]

Comment: Great answer for how to achieve an ESRI "Reference Scale"-like symbology behavior.